# Why does subscribe(subject) return AnyCancellable but subscribe(subscriber) Void?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm working with Swift Combine and do not get the difference between

```
func subscribe<S>(_ subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input
```

and

```
func subscribe<S>(_ subject: S) -> AnyCancellable where S : Subject, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Output
```

Why does one return an `AnyCancellable` wheras the other `Void`?

I have a custom `Subscriber` so is it totally safe for me to use

```
myPublisher.subscribe(myCustomSubscriber)
```

without having to deal with an `AnyCancellable`?

Answer (score 2):

*Update*:

As my explanation below, your custom `Subscriber` (I named it `MySubscriber` in the code below) should implement `Cancellable` protocol. Now you can manage the subscription by adding it to a `Set<AnyCancellable>`. When subscriber is cancelled, the subscription is canceled as well.

---

I have the same concern. I have a custom subscriber `Subscribers.MySubscriber` and want to add function `Publisher.mySubscriber()` like Combine did with `Subscribers.Sink` and `Publisher.sink()`. But I don't know how `Publisher.sink()` can return a `AnyCancellable`. After a few minutes, I guess a solution how `Publisher.sink()` is implemented:

```
extension Publisher {
    public func mySink(receiveCompletion: @escaping ((Subscribers.Completion<Self.Failure>) -> Void), receiveValue: @escaping ((Self.Output) -> Void)) -> AnyCancellable {
        let sink = Subscribers.Sink<Self.Output, Self.Failure>(receiveCompletion: receiveCompletion, receiveValue: receiveValue)
        subscribe(sink)
        return AnyCancellable(sink)
    }
}
```

So a customized subscriber should conform to `Cancellable`, and keep subscription reference, to cancel the subscription when subsriber's cancel() called, like below:

```
final class MySubscriber<Input, Failure: Error>: Subscriber, Cancellable {

    var subscription: Subscription?
    
    // ...
    
    init() {}

    func receive(subscription: Subscription) {
        // ...
        self.subscription = subscription
    }

    func receive(_ input: Input) -> Subscribers.Demand {
        // ...
        return .unlimited
    }

    func receive(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) {
        // ...
    }

    func cancel() {
        subscription?.cancel()
        subscription = nil
    }
}
```

So my function `Publisher.mySubscriber()` function will be:

```
extension Publisher {
    public func mySubscriber() -> AnyCancellable {
        let mySubscriber = MySubscriber<Output, Failure>()
        subscribe(mySubscriber)
        return AnyCancellable(mySubscriber)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

One expects a `Subscriber` and the other a `Subject`. Since your argument is a subscriber it will return an `AnyCancellable`.

Now, depending on the scope of that line, very likely you need to keep a reference of that `AnyCancellable` object. Either directly or by calling `store(:)` on it. You keep it so it's not deallocated before any Output or Failure is being published.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but it is a rare situation that requires a custom subscriber. You can often just use the `assign` or `sink` operators to make and attach a subscriber to the publisher.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question at all, unfortunately. I wanted to know WHY one does return an `AnyCancellable` and the other doesn't.

Comment: In the first form a subscriber exists, you have it in hand and pass the reference to it to a publisher with that function. When you do, you are telling the publisher to create a `Subscription` and call `receive(subscription)` on that subscriber.  In the second form you have no subscriber to begin with, just a `Subject` which is really a form of `Publisher`, but when you call that function a subscriber is created and returned to you. (which you then should keep a reference of)